# Evolution calendar notification with sound?

Tags: sound, notification, evolution, google, calendar

I'm trying to get desktop notifications with sound (a custom sound would be ideal, but just a sound for now is enough) for my upcoming google calendar appointments/events/whatever. I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.

Tried with KOrganizer but it doesn't seem to have desktop notifications, only alert popups. Also the syncing seems a bit slow.

Tried with Thunderbird and there's sound, but no desktop notifications, only optional alert popups. Minimum  sync rate is 30 minutes, and that's too much for me.

Tried with Evolution, sync can be configured to 1 minute, it has desktop notifications, but no sound!

Is there a way to add sound to Evolution desktop notifications (calendar ones, mail desktop notifications DO have sound)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This site contains a python script to make audible notifications work.

https://bazile.org/writing/2019/audible_gnome_notifications.html

The filters in this script may need tweaking (was the case for me).
Also contains a link to the github page with an installer script and systemd unit files.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: This answer was the only useful solution I found to that problem for my case. Just for completeness, here is the github link https://github.com/dbazile/gaudible. The script works by listening to the DCOP notifications, filtering out the calendar related stuff and playing a sound on a matching notification.