# no sound on calendar event (gnome - ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: gnome, sound, notification, evolution, calendar

I'd like to have sound notification on calendar events. Tried the tool from this post [Evolution calendar notification with sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227220/evolution-calendar-notification-with-sound) but I was unsuccessful getting it work.
When running `sudo ./install.sh` i get this error
`Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)`
anybody can help with detailed instruction how to use this tool or suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: try without `sudo`? otherwise you can do what the error suggests.

Comment: to be honest i've no idea what to do exactly. that's why i asked for detailed instruction

Comment: for one thing, there is no instruction to run `./install.sh` in any of the links I could reach from the one you provided. for another, why do you use `sudo`? none of the links recommended that either, and the errors you're getting are because `sudo` runs things as root, which does not have either of the variables defined (since it doesn't run a desktop session). If you do not need to run as root, then do not: just run it without `sudo`.

Comment: Just newbie to Linux world if anything fails I try next time with sudo :D  I cloned the git [link](https://github.com/dbazile/gaudible) from askubuntu link and simply executed the install on its folder (with/without sudo). The error gone after some tries without sudo and  I added 2 oga file to ~/.local/share/sounds/__custom/uncategorized and finally it works now. Thanks for pointing the root cause of problem